# htaccess : how to redirect all files in a folder to non subdomain if accessed via a subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

using htaccess, I need to remove the subdomain part of the url if a file is accessed in /folder/myfiles/

eg. I need to redirect 
sub.domain.com/folder/myfiles/anyfile.php
to
domain.com/folder/myfiles/anyfile.php

any file found in /folder/myfiles/ if accessed via a subdomain must be redirected to the same file on the root domain.

background: the site uses subdomains for wordpress blogs on multisite. There is a 3rd party app installed to a folder on the root domain, the licence is only valid for the root domain and attempting to access it via a subdomain invalidates the licence so I need to make sure that any file in that folder must only be accessed via the root domain and not a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder's .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/folder/myfiles/$1
```

In the root .htaccess or server config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/?(folder/myfiles(/.*)?)$ http://domain.com/$1
```

Comment: that worked perfectly for a chosen subdomain! I was able to edit it (the folder htaccess version) so it works for accessing from any subdomain with RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.com

thanks so much!